# How can I parse a JSON schema and create a default json object or generate a java class?

Tags: java, json

I'm sure someone has done this before:  A co-worker went through the trouble of making a JSON schema which can be used to validate a JSON object; however, I am lazy, and just want to generate a "default" empty JSON object from the schema.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I would like to do this in Java.

Failing this, is there a way to generate a Java class (NOT at run-time) based on this schema?

Muchas gracias, amigos.

Answer (score 7):

How about "[jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo)"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I could try GSON, but it wouldn't solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out [Java from JSON](http://javafromjson.dashingrocket.com).  It lets you paste JSON in and get source and compiled Jars.  There's also a standalone version.